# AngularJS - how to read a image file's data?

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

I suppose to send the `image` data's to back-end. for that, i am try to read the file ( image ). But I turn up with a error as :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'readAsArrayBuffer' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'.
```

how to fix it. or what is the correct way to read a image file?
here is my `directive'

```
var userPhotoUpload = function () {

    return {

        link : function (scope, element, attrs) {

            var photoInput = element.find('.uploadField');
            var r = new FileReader();

            element.on('click', function () {

                photoInput[0].click();

            });

            photoInput.on('change', function ( e ) {

                var data = event.target.result;
                r.readAsArrayBuffer(photoInput[0]);

                // console.log( "data", data, e.target.result );

            })

            // r.onloadend = function(e){

   //               var data = e.target.result;
   //               console.log( "let data load", data );
   //           //send you binary data via $http or $resource or do anything else with it
    //      }

        }

    }

}

angular.module("tcpApp")
    .directive('userPhotoUpload', userPhotoUpload );
```

Answer (score 0):

In oreder to upload a data on http request you can do in different ways 
as a file,as a byte array , binary but the easy way is as a file using  the following method is thee file from the input
see [here](https://jasonturim.wordpress.com/2013/09/12/angularjs-native-multi-file-upload-with-progress/) how to bind the directive with **documendata** variable

```
        $http(              
                { method: 'POST',
                  url: 'public/Game/store',
                  // headers:   {    'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'},
                  data: documentData
         });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with ng-flow's gallery upload

https://flowjs.github.io/ng-flow/